# How to set Java run time arguments in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, tomcat8

I have to set Java run time parameters for kerberos authentication. While running the stand alone executable jar the below argument was passed.

`java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kconfig/conf/jaas.conf  <exe jar>`

How to set this in tomcat 8 ?

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container. Why do you want to run jar on Tomcat? You can simply run it on jre.

Comment: Not running jar in tomcat , I used the command to run the jar and I wanted to know passing that commands in tomcat for a webservice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add following line(for linux) into /tomcat/bin/setenv.sh.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config={path to}/jaas.conf"
```

for windows add into \catalina-home\bin\catalina.bat

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config={path to}/jaas.conf"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add them to your `catalina.properties` like this:

`java.security.auth.login.config=./kconfig/conf/jaas.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your code :

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","./kconfig/conf/jaas.conf");
```

Also you can remove it using

```
System.clearProperty("java.security.auth.login.config");
```

or set it to empty

```
 System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","")
```

This way you get more flexibility.